# Filling forward based on two values (Time, ID)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2014 and I would like to fill forward based on two columns: Date and ID.
If ID change then I need to stop the previous filling forward

Here is my dataset:

```
   Date         Id       Score
--------------------------------------------
   201508         1           24
   201509         1           NULL
   201510         1           NULL
   201511         1           25
   201512         1           NULL
   201601         1           30
   201602         1           NULL
   201508         2           NULL
   201509         2           NULL
   201508         3           10
   201509         3           NULL
```

So I would like to get the following:

```
   Date         Id       Score
--------------------------------------------
   201508         1           24
   201509         1           24
   201510         1           24
   201511         1           25
   201512         1           25
   201601         1           30
   201602         1           30
   201508         2           NULL
   201509         2           NULL
   201508         3           10
   201509         3           10
```

I tried something like this but without success

```
SELECT
  a.*,
  COALESCE(a.Score, b.Score) AS FILLED_IN_VALUE
FROM 
  data a
  OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 x.Score
    FROM data x 
    WHERE 
      a.Score IS NULL 
      AND x.Score IS NOT NULL
      AND x.ID < a.ID
      AND x.Date < a.Date
    ORDER BY a.ID ASC, a.Date ASC
    ) b
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a running sum to classify rows into groups. Then get the max score per group.

```
select date,id,max(score) over(partition by id,grp) as score
from (select date,id,score,
      sum(case when score is not null then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by id order by date) as grp
      from tbl
     ) t
```

Comment: Works great. Thank you for your help